# single Jquery selection needs multiple $(

Tags: jquery

I've been working on a project and have found that I need to turn what I've selected with jquery back into a jquery object several times. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I don't know what it is.

```
$($($($(this).closest('tr')).children()[7]).children()[0]).removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: BTW if you need a complex selector like the one you are using, probably is a good idea use a ```class``` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq):

```
$(this).closest('tr').children().eq(7).children().eq(0).removeClass("hidden");
```

`.eq(0)` can also be written [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first):

```
$(this).closest('tr').children().eq(7).children().first().removeClass("hidden");
```

**Or** you could use the [`:eq` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (or [`:first` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) for the `:eq(0)` case) in `children`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').children(":eq(7)").children(":first").removeClass("hidden");
```

---

All of that said, I might well add a class to the target element so you can just do:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".the-class").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Surely there's a better way to do this. Too bad OP didn't show his HTML.  Closevoting as unclear.